# How to toggle fullscreen with lwjgl

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, glfw

I'm using glfw in lwjgl-3 to try to create a toggleFullscreen method. However it always gives me errors. I saw this question [Toggle Fullscreen at Runtime](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38620/toggle-fullscreen-at-runtime) but it didn't help because glfwOpenWindow() and glfwCloseWindow() don't exist for me. I guess lwjgl uses a differnt version of glfw? Does anyone know of a good solution for toggling fullscreen? thanks. this is my current code if it helps.

```
    public void toggleFullscreen(){
        long newWindow;
        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
        if(fullscreen){
            newWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Title", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), window.getWindowHandle());
            glfwMakeContextCurrent( newWindow );
        }else{
            newWindow = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Title", NULL, windowHandle());
            glfwMakeContextCurrent( newWindow );
        }
        glfwDestroyWindow(window.getWindowHandle());
        windowHandle = newWindow;

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowHandle);
        glfwSwapInterval(1);
        glfwShowWindow(windowHandle);
        GLContext.createFromCurrent();

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        GL11.glViewport(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);
        GL11.glOrtho(0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        game.initInputPolling();
    }
```

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: While it is impossible with GLFW at the moment, support is [coming in GLFW 3.2](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/43).